# Can we use other class in SortedSet interface

Tags: java, collections

The below code gives the sorted elements & SortedSet can't be instantiated as it is interface & hence TreeSet is used to instantiate it as it is a class & my question is why does TreeSet is used instead of any other classes is it because SortedSet gives sorted order element & hence TreeSet is used?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SortedSetDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        SortedSet s=new TreeSet();
        s.add("Akash");
        s.add("Prakash");
        s.add("Bhushan");
        s.add("Chetan");
        System.out.println("SortedSet:");
        Iterator itr=s.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
SortedSet:
Akash
Bhushan
Chetan
Prakash

Comment: Have you looked at the Java Docs to see what else implements that interface?

Comment: It is confusing you mentioned `TreeMap`, but the code only uses `TreeSet`. BTW, what do you miss from `TreeSet`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html `TreeSet` is one of the classes which implements the `SortedSet` interface. It is a good practice to work against the interface so that you are implementation-independent. But of course you can take another implementation of `SortedSet`

Answer (score 0):

You can put any concrete class on the right side that implements `SortedSet`.

TreeSet implements SortedSet. See Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html